# java error using ArrayLists - wont compile

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Here is what I have to do:

> Write a method that takes an ArrayList of Integer objects and returns
>   an ArrayList of Character objects of the same size.  The returned
>   elements of the Arryalist are assigned a letter grade corrsponding to
>   the integer grade of the same index element of the ArrayList
>   parameter.   (A if 90 or above,...,F if less than 60).  Include the
>   code to test your method.

Here is what I have:

```
package returninggrade;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReturningGrade {

    public static ArrayList main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Character> getEquivalen (ArrayList < Integer > mark) {
            ArrayList<Character> cArray = new ArrayList<Character>();      // create ArrayListr to return

            // loop throught Int arrayList
            for (int i = 0; i < mark.size(); i++) {
                // extract value
                int value = mark.get(i);
                // convert value to char
                if (value > 90) {
                    cArray.add(new Character('A'));
                } else if (value > 80) {
                    cArray.add(new Character('B'));
                } else if (value > 70) {
                    cArray.add(new Character('C'));
                } else if (value > 60) {
                    cArray.add(new Character('D'));
                } else {
                    cArray.add(new Character('E'));
                }
            }
            // return ArrayList of Char
            return cArray;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I am getting an error and I am stuck:

> ```
> ArrayList<Character> getEquivalen(ArrayList<Integer> mark)
> ```

The suggestion NetBeans is giving is that a ";" is expected, however when I add it in, I get the same exact error. Any help?

Comment: You're attempting to declare a method *inside* your `main()` method. That's ... not legal (aside from not making any sense).

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to define a method inside of `main()`.  You can't do that.  Your signature for `main` is also incorrect - it *must* be `public static void main(String[] foo)`.  The `foo` is a variable name; conventionally it's `args`, but it *could* be whatever you like.

Extract your method and declare it *before* `main`:

```
ArrayList<Character> getEquivalen (ArrayList < Integer > mark) {
    ArrayList<Character> cArray = new ArrayList<Character>();      // create ArrayListr to return

    // loop throught Int arrayList
    for (int i = 0; i < mark.size(); i++) {
        // extract value
        int value = mark.get(i);
        // convert value to char
        if (value > 90) {
            cArray.add(new Character('A'));
        } else if (value > 80) {
            cArray.add(new Character('B'));
        } else if (value > 70) {
            cArray.add(new Character('C'));
        } else if (value > 60) {
            cArray.add(new Character('D'));
        } else {
            cArray.add(new Character('E'));
        }
    }
    // return ArrayList of Char
    return cArray;
}
```

Then, call it inside of main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReturningGrade rg = new ReturningGrade();
    rg.getEquivalen(new ArrayList<Integer>());  // you have to provide the ArrayList here
}
```